# What does suffix -al convey in Semigroupal in contrast to Semigroup?

Tags: scala, terminology, scala-cats

There exist Semigroup and Semigrup**al**

```
Semigroup[Int].combine(1, 41)                  // : Int = 42
Semigroupal[Option].product(Some(1), Some(41)) // : Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(value = (1, 41))
```

What is -al suffix meant to convey? In what sense does -al convey the distinction between Semigroup and Semigroupal? Similarly there is language of Monoid and Monoid**al**; is -al here conveying the distinction along the same lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this paper on [semigroupal categories](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/TQFT/Boyarchenko%20on%20associativity.pdf). I don't believe a `Semigroupal` has to actually represent a semigroupal category, but its `product` operation is something semigroupal categories have as well.

> Similarly there is language of Monoid and Monoidal; is -al here conveying the distinction along the same lines?

Yes, it's related in the same way (but [monoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category) seem to be much more widely used).

Comment: I see, according to the paper, a semigroupal category is a triple (M, ⊗, α), so `cats.Semigroupal#product` would correspond to just semigroup**al functor** ⊗? Regarding -al, is it meant to convey just that the binary operation of a category has the associativity aspect of the semigroup?

Comment: Hmm doesn't the word functor indicate presence of `map`, but `cats.Semigroupal` just has `product`, so maybe the name is not a shorthand for semigroupal functor? I guess it would be more correct to call `cats.Apply` a semigroupal functor, as it extends both `Functor` and `Semigroupal`?

Comment: I thought about saying something like "`Semigroupal` gestures at semigroupal categories" instead. "I guess it would be more correct to call cats.Apply a semigroupal functor, as it extends both Functor and Semigroupal?" Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 4):

edmundnoble states semigroupal is an [abbreviation](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats?at=5b737273a37112689c1eedf5)

> Semigroupal is an abbreviation for semigroupal functor which is to a monoidal functor as a semigroup is to a monoid

or as [hrhino](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats?at=59de66063cb340a261118f6d) puts it

> "semigroupal functor" - "functor" = "semigroupal"

`cats.Semigroupal` points towards the concept of semigroup**al functor** which is defined something like

```
trait SemigroupalFunctor[F[_]] {
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

semigroupal functor is like monoidal functor without the unit

```
trait MonoidalFunctor[F[_]] {
  def unit: F[Unit]
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

Now `cats.Semigroupal` is a generalisation of semigroupal functor where only the `product` is extracted into its own type class

```
trait Semigroupal[F[_]] {
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
}
```

hence the naming stops at just `Semigroupal` instead of `SemigroupalFunctor`. The full semigroupal functor can be found in cats in the form of `Apply` which combines `Semigroupal` and `Functor` as shown in the following simplified view

```
trait Semigroupal[F[_]] {
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
}

trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

trait Apply[F[_]] extends Semigroupal[F] with Functor[F] { 
  def ap[A, B](ff: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B]
}
```

Semigroupal used to be called Cartesian until [rename Cartesian to Semigroupal #1961](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/1961)

Comment: Is the “al” trying to change a noun to an adjective?  How is semigroupal related to semigroup?  One has product while the other has combine, is it different form of combine? @mario galic